# Why did Bionic kernel update to 4.15.0-24 get removed from the repos?

Tags: kernel, 18.04

This kernel update was pushed out on Monday, and I updated most of our systems to it.

Today I got around to updating the last system, and the kernel update was not available.  It appears that it was yanked from the repos.

On the system I tried to update today:

> ```
> apt policy linux-generic
> linux-generic:
>   Installed: 4.15.0.23.25
>   Candidate: 4.15.0.23.25
>   Version table:
>  *** 4.15.0.23.25 500
>         500 [my local mirror]
> ```

On the systems updated Monday

```
apt policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 4.15.0.24.26
  Candidate: 4.15.0.24.26
  Version table:
 *** 4.15.0.24.26 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Also my one remaining 16.04 system got this update Monday, and now it shows local/obsolete in synaptic.

[image]

Where can I see why this was done, and what are the consequences of remaining on this LTS kernel that was bad enough to be pulled back?

Related: [Strategy to deal with Canonical's increasingly poor QA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897456/strategy-to-deal-with-canonicals-increasingly-poor-qa)

Comment: `apt policy linux-generic` shows `4.15.0.24.26` for  both Installed and Candidate.

Comment: Interesting.  I just tried a manual installation of the 24 kernel and it broke my VirtualBox setup I had.  As far as the linux-generic is showing the highest version it wants to install is 23.  The updates and security repos are enabled.

Comment: Yes my experience today was the same as @Terrance . Running an apt-update/apt-upgrade did not install the new kernel, where as on Monday it did.

Comment: @Rinzwind synaptic shows linux-generic in the 'local/obsolete' category, and `apt policy` agrees, see edited question.

Comment: OrganicMarble, Which server are you using for your repositories? I do not see what you and @Terrance see. I see 4.15.0.24.26 both in an up to date Ubuntu, an up to date Lubuntu and a not fully up to date persistent live Lubuntu (all 18.04 LTS). And my VirtualBox is still working in the Ubuntu system. Maybe this is related to [Long boot delay on Ubuntu ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o).

Comment: @sudodus I think it has to do with when you upgraded.  I am actually performing a clean install on a system right now to confirm this.  There was a posting as well here where someone complained up upgrading to the 4.15.0-24 kernel and their system crashed.

Comment: @Terrance, But in the persistent live Lubuntu, `apt-cache` also finds the candidate 4.15.0.24.26

Comment: @sudodus I have a local mirror that pulls from us.archive.ubuntu.com for my 18.04 systems. But note that on my one remaining 16.04 system, which does not use the mirror, the exact same thing happened. It got updated to the 4.15.0.24 kernel on Monday, and now that is showing local/obsolete in synaptic.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I use a Swedish mirror for the installed systems and `archive/ubuntu.com` is used by the persistent live system

Comment: The new kernel actually has worked OK for me, except that it broke Wake-on-LAN by design (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051822/wake-on-lan-quit-working-with-latest-kernel-bionic) I'm just worried that all my systems are running on something they opted to pull back.

Comment: Yep, on a clean install right now it will only upgrade to 4.15.0-23.  I do indeed have updates and security enabled on the clean install.

Comment: Myself and many others have been having issues with Wi-Fi networks being found after updating to 14.15.0-24. I am attempting to fix the issue on my system right now... Probably have to go back to 23... Just a thought... May be why it was removed.

Comment: Now 'my' mirrors are downgraded to 4.15.0-23-25. Obviously they were slower than the US mirror.

Comment: For anyone running the 4.15.0-24 kernel with Wifi issues, please see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1052418/231142

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux/+bug/1779827

Once this Critical bug was reported with enough detail, Canonical engineers and community volunteer testers bisected the problem and had a patch within 36 hours.

Note that this bug was critical, and worthy of pulling because *booting at GRUB from previous kernels wasn't a viable workaround*. Some folks reporting had to reinstall to restore functionality.

Comment: Interesting. I use lightdm and not gdm which may be why my systems didn't break.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I am going to agree with you.  My systems that run LightDM have been working fine.  My VirtualBox runs GDM and it crashed when I installed the 24.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, Just to add confusion: I have gdm in Ubuntu and lightdm in Lubuntu and both are working with 4.15.0.24.26. But I understand from the current bug reports, that several systems are affected by very serious problems. (And the mirrors are not updated at the same time, which can explain why we have seen different versions.)

Comment: @sudodus Indeed, there are many variables. At first I thought my last system wasn't being updated because it was 32 bit...