# Why a system crash after latest kernel upgrade to 4.15.0-24?

Tags: 16.04, kernel

**System:**     Custom, Intel(R) DZ68DB, Nvidia(R) GeForce 8400GS, 16GB ram,
            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04.2

**Problem:**

- Latest upgrades included kernel 4.15.0-24.
- Performed upgrade and upon reboot, the system boots, then screen goes black, bottom half of screen shows green horizontal lines for a second, goes black, and just keeps cycling that way.
- Tried shutdown/restart and the same thing occurs.
- Rebooted system and chose previous kernel 4.13.0-43 and the system booted up and is running fine.

So...has anyone else had the same problem?
I would like to upgrade to 18.04 but am now 
somewhat spooked.

Comment: @Terrance Do you have Bionic-updates enabled?  I `apt list linux-generic -a` shows that linux-generic in bionic-updates is 24

Comment: @Terrance Weirdness!

Comment: @Terrance But it's still listed in the updates.  Do you think perhaps this is an issue with VirtualBox (I use kvm for my linux boxes, and run bionic on hardware)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I guess I can always try it directly on my hardware and see.  I think I have a laptop here somewhere that doesn't have an OS on it at the moment that I can try for direct hardware.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Indeed it looks like it has been pulled for the time being.  Just performed the clean install on a laptop and the highest it will go is 4.15.0-23

Comment: Please see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1052210/231142

Comment: @Terrance Was offline for several hours - I think that's a good catch, and apparently my system hardware was unaffected by the bug, whilst the 'hardware' of the VirtualBox system was

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my considered opinion, the issue is related to the incompatibility between the 4.15 kernel and the Nvidia driver (340, in my case).

Steps I took to solve the problem:

1. At the boot I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and went to the grub options.
2. I chose the 4.13 kernel and the system booted up.
3. I installed `grub-customizer` and changed the kernel position at boot, to avoid do the same each time... But this process is not so complicated because we had already the previous 4.13 kernel installed, because this was not a 18.04 fresh install.

#### Optional:

4. You may enter the following command in a terminal:

   ```
    sudo apt install haveged,
   ```

as described [in this bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux/+bug/1779827)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1052936/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: "apt install haveged" didn't work for me.