# Updater - what to choose to guarantee working system after reboot?

Tags: boot, updates

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm running 18.04 LTS and a few weeks ago unfortunately I ran into a bad kernel bug by accidentally downloading it via updater.

That time I simply confirmed everything that came in as suggested update. After this a reboot was not possible anymore and I had to do many things to get the system back up and running.

Now the updater again reports many new features and updates coming in. I definitely don't want to go through a new kernel update again. How do I know which modules I can select for download that the system is working again after reboot?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I recall an issue like what you describe due to a software bug; which was just bad luck for the very-few that were effected by it. Once it was reported (via launchpad), it was soon fixed, but would still have been annoying for anyone affected.  You could limit yourself to `apt upgrade` (rather than `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade`), but you'd also become more vulnerable to security-flaws as you'd not be getting all updates which wouldn't be wise depending on your use case.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an option to check on the GUI Software updater as well? (I mean apt upgrade instead if dist-upgrade or full-upgrade)

Comment: For future issues with kernel: you can pick the old kernel during booting when grub shows up.

Comment: @guiverc maybe this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052159/why-did-bionic-kernel-update-to-4-15-0-24-get-removed-from-the-repos ? Also worth mentioning is that that using the GUI with Ubuntu's software manager may afford phased updates (and so some extent of safety).

Comment: @DKBose if it can be done via GUI, someone else (you?) will need to answer.  Alas I'm only familiar with terminal; unsuitable for this OP or answer...

Comment: Set your update policy to every two weeks. Check here if other Ubuntu 18.04 users have had problems with recent updates before you apply yours. Use 16.04 instead for a couple of years until 18.04 development cycle slows down. Just a few thoughts, not the answer you seek.