# Is apt full-upgrade safe?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I tend to obsessively want to upgrade everything I can, so I run the Software Updater GUI tool and also `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and blindly install everything. It seems the command line often has packages to update when the GUI doesn't. I'm running 20.04.

Is my practice safe or do I stand a chance of breaking something? What's the recommended way of keeping everything as up to date as possible without breaking things?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Software Updater GUI does exactly the same.

Comment: @Pilot6 frequently full-upgrade will install packages when the GUI doesn't. This makes me wonder if I shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: It doesn't matter much. If you don't connect PPAs or some unofficial kernels, yhat shouldn't break anything.

Comment: @Pilot6 by safe I mean it won't leave the system or programs in an unusable or unnecessary buggy state.

Comment: It depends on what you did before. The command itself is safe on a healthy system.

Comment: On a stable release, which 20.04 is at this time, `sudo apt upgrade` is sufficient. `full-upgrade` is there if a package update requires that some other package is uninstalled. That often happens on the development release, but never on stable releases.

Comment: Hmmm. Please provide an example of "*full-upgrade will install packages when the GUI doesn't*". The *recommended* way of keeping up to date with security upgrades is Unattended-Upgrades. Anything beyond that seems a personal preference. Advice: You can spend a couple afternoons obsessively learning how apt works, then help answer questions like these.

Comment: @user535733 I have also often experienced the GUI not updating all programs. I quit using it and use aptitude for that reason. I will follow this post and report back when it happens again.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I suspect it's ordinary confusion about [phased updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates), but an example will avoid guessing.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, which DE are you using? I wonder if phased updates apply only to Ubuntu or to all flavors given that a specific package manager [seems to be involved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052710/is-updating-via-synaptic-or-muon-or-plasma-discover-covered-by-phased-updates).

Comment: @DKBose I use stock Ubuntu but with LXDE desktop on most of my systems. Again, I'll keep an eye out for evidence, but what I've seen is that after running the GUI "Software Updater" app, if I go run `aptitude`, there are more updates to be done. So I just quit running the GUI since I had to run `aptitude` anyway.

Comment: @DKBose I reproduced it, and have posted a question so that I could include images https://askubuntu.com/q/1246915/243321

Comment: @user535733 evidence is in this question https://askubuntu.com/q/1246915/243321

Comment: So, it got closed as a duplicate (appropriately) and the answer for me is, never use the gui, continue to use `aptitude` so I get all the updates.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### You should use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` instead.

Most of the differences between `apt` and `apt-get` are cosmetic. The major exception is the `upgrade` action, which actually behaves in a markedly different way. With `apt`, the `upgrade` action is nearly always sufficient, and most of the old advice suggesting otherwise does not apply to `apt upgrade`.

Unlike `apt-get upgrade`, `apt upgrade` can install new packages to satisfy dependencies. The `full-upgrade` action (and `dist-upgrade`, which is a synonym) can do this too, but it also can *remove* packages, including packages marked as having been manually installed.

Most advice to run `full-upgrade` (or its synonym `dist-upgrade`) is a vestige of a time when there was no `apt` command. Commands with `full-upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` require special care to be used safely, and there's no good reason even for very experienced users to run them routinely.

Furthermore, although using `full-upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` *and closely inspecting what it proposes to do* used to be widely recommended, this recommendation was questionable even at the time. If for some reason you do want to use `apt-get` instead of `apt` to achieve the same effect as `apt upgrade`, you can run `apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs`.

---

To recap, for what you're currently doing, this is the command you probably want:

```bsh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

And if for some reason you preferred to use `apt-get` instead of `apt`, you could use this:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs
```

There is no need to use `full-upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` for routine installation of updates. In a stable release of Ubuntu (whether LTS or non-LTS), it is uncommon to need to remove packages in order to upgrade other packages. You might occasionally encounter this situation when using PPAs or other third-party repositories, but even then, you should be very careful, and `full-upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` would still not be something you'd often need.

---

Finally, note that one major situation where new packages are installed (which `apt upgrade` will do) is kernel updates. Most kernel updates install the new kernel as a separate package, so that you can still boot into the older kernel if the new one doesn't work. Especially if you're only updating from the command line, old kernels can gradually accumulate and take up space. *That is still **not** a situation that `full-upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` would prevent or address.* Instead, to uninstall most old kernels from the command-line, you can use:

```bsh
sudo apt autoremove
```

What this really does is to remove packages that were installed automatically as dependencies and that are no longer needed. It can, and sometimes will, remove packages other than old kernels. It is generally safe to run, but I do suggest looking at what it says it's going to do before proceeding.

Comment: Your answer is correct - but I understood through other posts that `full-upgrade` is important to be used in the process to upgrade the complete OS - of course using other commands to accomplish the goal, for example from 18:04 to 20:04 or from 20:04 to 22:04