# Why doesn't "Software Updater" update all software?

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates

(this question is a follow-on to discussion in comment about this question: [Is apt full-upgrade safe?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1246828/243321))

Ubuntu 18.04, LXDE desktop, 64 bit

Today I was notified by Software Updater that there was software to update.

[image]

I ran the updates and got this result

[image]

Then when I run `aptitude`, there is more to do

[image]

Why doesn't Software Updater update all software?